# How can I create a custom Ribbon control with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls, ribbon

I want to be able to add a `DatePicker` to one of my Ribbon's tabs and have the space and size managed by the `Ribbon`. Particularly, I want to create a custom `Ribbon` control that will have a `Ribbon` control `Label` attribute available. I'm not sure how to solve this without multiple inheritance (inheriting from `DatePicker` and `RibbonControl`).

Is there a `RibbonControl` interface that will grant me access to the Label attribute of the control without having to define custom formatting? Will I have to abandon the ribbon and create a custom tabbed interface instead?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you would like to create a custom ribbon, whether you want a ribbon with which you could interact. i am proving you a link here, you could download the source code and modify it as you want. here it show they have added a drop down list. you could add a date picker too.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23199/WPF-C-Ribbon-Control-Library

if it helps you. you are welcome in advance